# How to forcefully redraw a swift ui view within a button action call

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui

So I'm doing something sort of jank, but I need to do it for a class that I am taking

I need to update the view after every step of a while loop that is inside of a button's action: callback, in order to create a really simple "animation"

is there any way to get a swift UI view to drop everything and redraw immediately?

code for my button:

```
                Button(action: {
                    pass_again = true;
                    while(pass_again){
                        (right_text, pass_again) = twos.collapse(dir: Direction.right)
                        cur_id+=1
                        usleep(1000000)
                        // I need to redraw the UI here 
                    }
                    twos.spawn()
                }, label: {
                    Text(right_text)
                }).padding(0.5)
```

Comment: There really isn't enough code there to answer the question well for you. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). However, if you are changing an `@State` variable, that will cause a view redraw.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an `@State` variable to any SwiftUI view i.e. `Text(self.yourvar)`, so any time you change the `@State` value it will automatically update the text or any other property bonded with it.

About the animation you can use `.withAnimation` modifier to create a simple animation that swiftUI will perform

```
withAnimation {
    your state var updates goes here
}
```